# Can we use az rest in ARM deployment scripts?

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-cli, azure-cli2

I am using ARM Deploymentscripts AzCli. Can we use `az rest` in ARM deployment scripts?
I am getting `Forbidden({"error":{"code":"Authorization_RequestDenied","message":"Insufficient privileges to complete the operation."`

Comment: Can you post the section of the ARM template that you believe is giving you this issue? Also what are you trying to achieve as I am struggling to see the use of using the CLI in an ARM template.

Comment: `"scriptContent": "landingPageApp=$(az rest --method POST --headers \"Content-Type=application/json\" --uri https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications --body '{\"displayName\": \"LandingpageAppARM\"'"`

Comment: trying to create an app registration using `"type": "Microsoft.Resources/deploymentScripts",` and running above script

Comment: actually none of `az rest` command are working in the container

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can reproduce your issue on my side, it means your user-assigned identity(MSI) does not have enough permissions to create the AD App via Microsoft Graph in your tenant.

To solve this issue, just give an AAD admin role e.g. `Application administrator` to the service principal of your MSI, follow the steps below.

1.Navigate to the `Azure Active Directory` in the portal -> `Roles and administrators` -> click `Application administrator`.

[image]

2.Click `Add assignments` -> `Select member(s)` -> search for the name of your MSI -> add it.

[image]

[image]

**Note:** You can also give the Microsoft Graph application permission `Application.ReadWrite.All` to the MSI instead of `Application administrator`, won't say too much here, if you are interested in it, let me know, I can post it.

**Besides**, if you just want to create the AD App with Azure CLI, actually no need to use `az rest` manually, you can use the built-in command [`az ad app create`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ad/app?view=azure-cli-latest#az_ad_app_create) directly.

**Test sample:**

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "identity": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "utcValue": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "[utcNow()]"
    }
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deploymentScripts",
      "apiVersion": "2020-10-01",
      "name": "runAzureCLI",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "kind": "AzureCLI",
      "identity": {
        "type": "UserAssigned",
        "userAssignedIdentities": {
          "[parameters('identity')]": {
          }
        }
      },
      "properties": {
        "forceUpdateTag": "[parameters('utcValue')]",
        "AzCliVersion": "2.15.0",
        "timeout": "PT30M",
        "scriptContent": "landingPageApp=$(az rest --method POST --headers \"Content-Type=application/json\" --uri https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications --body '{\"displayName\": \"LandingpageAppARM\"}')",
        "cleanupPreference": "OnSuccess",
        "retentionInterval": "P1D"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: oh right, il try and see what is the minimum permissions needed to do this.

Comment: thank @joy, i should have tried this. Application developer works too :-), thanks for pointing out!